# Error in glmmTMB after Matrix update: negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

Tags: r, matrix, glmmtmb, glmm, tmb

I'm modeling camera trap data (counts) with camera site as a random effect and landscape-level covariates + season as fixed effects, and an offset for number of days the camera station was active, as below:

```
mod2 <- glmmTMB(Coyote ~ develop + PERCENTILE + season + (1|site), 
                offset = log(days.active),
                data = all_dat, family = "nbinom2")
```

and am, as of today, encountering the following error message:

> Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
> negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

I have about 400 observations in my data. I only get this error when the offset is included, and it happens with both a negative binomial and Poisson model. My code was working just fine until it suddenly didn't, so I assume the issue was related to the recent Matrix changes and associated dependencies in TMB, as detailed in similar questions [here with the same error in glmmTMB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466641/error-in-fittmbtmbstruc-negative-log-likelihood-is-nan-at-starting-parameter) and [here with a similar issue in lme4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481539/error-in-initializeptr-function-cholmod-factor-ldeta-not-provided-by-pack). However, none of the solutions in the links have worked for me (I tried commenting instead of opening a new question but wasn't able to as my account is new). I'm on macOS 12.5.

I have tried:

1. Reinstall Matrix to version 1.6-2 as suggested by an answer in the first link using install_versions from the remotes package
2. Reinstall Matrix from source (version 1.6-3) and also reinstall TMB and glmmTMB as suggested by the Matrix dev in the second link -- I tried this both ways suggested in the answer, by installing TMB/glmmTMB from the source and then trying to install a compatible binary from CRAN
3. Reinstall Matrix from the source (version 1.6-3) and only reinstall glmmTMB from source, as installing TMB from source resulted in version discrepancies between glmmTMB and TMB
4. Updated R and tried all of the above again

Both reinstallation methods didn't work at all for me until I installed gfortran, but now they are at least installing -- just not solving my issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: #3 is surprising.  Does `install.packages("Matrix", type = "source"); install.packages("TMB", type = "source"); install.package("glmmTMB", type = "source"); library("glmmTMB")` really give a warning?  Maybe you have multiple copies of one package installed?  What does `installed.packages() |> as.data.frame() |> subset(Package=="Matrix", select=c(Package, LibPath, Version))` (and similarly for `TMB` and `glmmTMB`) show you?

Comment: I tried again and it's no longer showing a warning! I probably did have multiple copies installed at some point with all of my reinstallation attempts. Glad I have everything loaded properly from source now, but unfortunately it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have any observations with 0 days active in your data set??

Comment: We found similar errors in our GitHub workflows that run our testthat-files (and indeed, those tests worked before and suddently stopped working). It happend after the update of the _Matrix_ and _MatrixModels_ packages, so I guess it _might_ be related (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/77530214/2094622). Maybe it is important to also install _MatrixModels_ from source after installing the _Matrix_ package?

Comment: `glmmTMB` doesn't use `MatrixModels`. Looking at glmmTMB's [DESCRIPTION file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html) reminds me that `glmmTMB` also links to `RcppEigen`, which might also need re-installing?

Comment: Another guess, based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466641/error-in-fittmbtmbstruc-negative-log-likelihood-is-nan-at-starting-parameter#comment136641405_77504843); try `remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.6-2")` ?  (That *shouldn't* be necessary but if it works ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I can easily get this error if I have a 0 in the variable that I am logging in order to get the offset (which would be `any(all_dat$days.active == 0)` in your case):

```r
library(glmmTMB)
data("sleepstudy", package = "lme4")
ss <- transform(sleepstudy, offset = c(0, rep(1, nrow(sleepstudy)-1)))
m1 <- glmmTMB(round(Reaction)~ Days, family = nbinom2, data = ss)  ## works fine
m2 <- update(m1, offset = log(offset))
```

> Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
> negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

(However, this is **not** consistent with "it was working before but then it stopped working", as this error should have happened with previous versions of the package too ...)